# Not receiving emails after latest update "CRM Online 2015 Update 1"

Tags: email, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2015

This weekend had Update 1 for my organization on CRM Online 2015 (7.1.1.3149) and since then we are not receiving emails into CRM. We use email router, everything has been checked, version, tested connection, approved emails, .... . We are able to send emails from CRM but we are not getting responses back.

Anyone else going through the same problem? Any ideas to get it solved?

We use Gmail for most of our mailing and POP/SMTP through EmailRouter to get it in and out of CRM.

Already opened a service request, but last response was "an internal investigation was submitted to our Operations Team...." with no estimate for a response time.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: To make things worse, not just haven't received a response back from Microsoft Support, but now can't send emails neither.

Error Log: 10/23/2015 10:36:15 : #23379 - Could not verify the version of Microsoft Dynamics CRM at https://disco.crm.dynamics.com/yourorgname. An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar issue (crm online, upgrade to 7.1, router no longer working) doing this:

1. delete all configurations inside email router
2. update email router to latest version (it wasn't the latest)
3. re-create all configurations from scratch, ending up with the exact same settings I had before

Answer (score 0):

In this case updating the Email Router was the problem. Looking into windows update noticed EmailRouter was updated (Update 1.1 - 7.1.0001) the day before the problem started. Looking further about this update found [this thread](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/p/178903/440514).

Uninstalling Update 1.1 resolved the issue.

Also disabled automatic updates for other Microsoft products on windows update settings.

Comment: Disable auto updates on prod Environments is highly recommended, it's very Forrest Gump.